# AndroidX ActivityResultContracts package not found / class not found

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-appcompat, androidx

According to [this documentation from Google about launching an activity to get a result](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result):

> While the underlying startActivityForResult() and onActivityResult()
>   APIs are available on the Activity class on all API levels, it is
>   strongly recommended to use the Activity Result APIs introduced in
>   AndroidX Activity 1.2.0-alpha02 and Fragment 1.3.0-alpha02.

I want to let my users take a photo from within my app and get that photo data back to my app. I was going to use the old startActivityForResult() but this new method looks like it will solve lots of problems and be more reliable, so I wanted to give it a try. I'm supposed to be able to call `registerForActivityResult()` and pass it a built-in contract for taking a picture called [ActivityResultsContracts.TakePicture](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture):

```
this.registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture(), ...);
```

But I get: `error: package ActivityResultContracts does not exist`

I've added this to my app/build.gradle:

```
// original include
//implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'

// suggestion from Google documentation
//implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0-alpha02'

// AndroidStudio suggested a newer version was available
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0-beta01'
```

I tried the `alpha02` and the `beta01` and neither of them seem to have the classes referred to in the documentation.

When I try to import the class manually at the top of my java file, AndroidStudio doesn't think the package exists either. It should be `androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture`, but this is what I see:

[image: screenshot of Android Studio auto-complete package list in import statement]

I'm using gradle 3.5.3 if that matters at all. (Whenever I try to upgrade to the latest gradle, my project goes insane, so I've just been staying with the version that works.)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

From the quoted documentation:

> it is strongly recommended to use the Activity Result APIs introduced in AndroidX Activity 1.2.0-alpha02 and Fragment 1.3.0-alpha02.

Neither of those are in your dependencies, at least the portion from your question. You have been manipulating `appcompat`, not `activity` or `fragment`.

Add either or both of:

```
implementation "androidx.activity:activity:1.2.0"
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.0"
```

(or any higher versions)

Comment: Ohhhh.... /facepalm. Thank you. I saw `androidx` in my implementation line for the appcompat and just updated the version number without even noticing it was specifically just appcompat and not the activity package. Thanks again!

Comment: I had a similar issue (unresolved method `registerForActivityResult`)  even if I did have the two dependencies listed in the Gradle file. However they were for alpha version 02, as per Google documentation. The problem was solved when I changed them to 04 as per [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) recommendation. Thanks a lot!

Comment: For some reason I added these (and their newer versions) to some old project and it couldn't find the function, while it works fine on a POC. How could it be? This is what I added: `    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.0-rc01"
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.0-rc01"
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity:1.2.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.2.0-rc01'`

Comment: @androiddeveloper: You do not need the duplicates -- the `-ktx` artifacts should be pulling in the non-`-ktx` artifacts. However, I do not know why you are running into problems. For example, [here is `ActivityResultsContracts`](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/activity/activity/1.2.0-rc01-source/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.java.html) for `androidx.activity:activity:1.2.0-rc01`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Using just `androidx.activity:activity:1.2.0-rc01` also didn't help. Only similar function it allows me to use is `registerStartActivityForResultReceiver`, and it's very different... In POC it works fine (I used `implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.0-rc01"` there). Is it possible it's because of a warning of `Plugin version (1.4.21) is not the same as library version (1.3.72) `  (even though I've set it to 1.4.21 everywhere) ?

Comment: @CommonsWare I think it's a bug of the IDE or its plugins. It seems the IDE can't help with it (meaning it's mostly a visual issue), but building, creating APK and launching - all works fine... Wrote about this here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/178403178 and here : https://www.reddit.com/r/android_devs/comments/l4qmo5/cant_use_registerforactivityresult_even_though_i/gkt2srk/?context=3

Comment: @androiddeveloper: I have run into that sort of problem before with Studio, where the IDE yells but the project builds just fine. I do not recall encountering a case where a function was missing, but I have definitely seen cases where Studio claimed that classes do not exist when they did. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @CommonsWare I had this sometimes with view-binding, but somehow it got solved on its own (or I used invalidate-cache for this). Here no matter what I try it doesn't help. I hate seeing red-underlines :)

Comment: you sir deserve true glory, your personal space in heaven and 72 virgins granted twice...
Thanks for saving my day

Comment: Damn this was all about the imports. This is so complicated by Google! Everything works fine without this import.

Comment: Added both - still have the issue. Actually, added the higher versions `1.4.0` but I'm still seeing this error.

Comment: Please refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70919493/function-registerforactivityresult-not-exist too

Comment: I see the same thing as @androiddeveloper, the IDE isn't happy but the project builds and runs.   I swear in the last 6 months the IDE has gotten increasingly buggy.

Answer (score 22):

I was having the same problem. When I upgraded androidx.appcompat from version 1.2.0 to 1.3.1, the problem went away. There's no need to add androidx.activity or androidx.fragment dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    ...
}
```

Comment: This worked too! So basically I tried adding the fragment library but thus worked just fine!

Comment: Thanks. You can find the latest versions on https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but instead of adding something I erased the `appcompat` implementation that probably caused the problem because after it everything worked just fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and neither option work for me I import
"import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;" this in my activity and it works.

I am using "'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'" library

Comment: implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'
 
use it. its works for me

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still facing this issue and tried all the things, check the modules that you have added in your project, it's very much possible that one of the module has implemented older version of `androidx.appcompat:appcompat`

In my case, I had added 'nativetemplates' module for Admob native ads, which had older version of `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0`, I simply updated it to latest version and it resolved the issue.