# error: package androidx.activity.result does not exist import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResult; in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic-framework, vuejs2, ionic4

I am trying to compile my ionic app in android studion but receiving this error

```
error: package androidx.activity.result does not exist import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResult; in android studio
```

How i can solve this issue

buil.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'src/main/libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.apache.cordova:framework:$cordovaAndroidVersion"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START

    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}
```

Comment: maybe the code line is written wrongly, try to check out the code and write in this way import androidx.activity.result.*;   or import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResult;

Comment: Not working this one

Comment: Please share the dependencies that you've implemented at build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61622254/androidx-activityresultcontracts-package-not-found-class-not-found) before? Please try it. You need to add `androidx.appcompat:appcompat` and `androidx.activity:activity` dependencies

Comment: Now i am facing this issue `error: cannot find symbol
import com.getcapacitor.PermissionState;
                       ^
  symbol:   class PermissionState
  location: package com.getcapacitor`

Comment: @webpakistan I think you have cloned a project but you didn't copy the dependencies. I think you'll face these issues again on this project. It is better to find the dependencies.

Comment: I just added camera plugins