# Function registerForActivityResult not Exist

Tags: android, android-intent

i have tried all solutions in internet to resolve this issue but no one is worked

i am using dependencies

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-beta01'  
implementation "androidx.activity:activity:1.2.0-alpha07"  
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.0-alpha07"
```

[image: enter image enter code heredescription here]

here is
my MainActivity Class where i use the function .. i don't know if the problem in ***AppCompatActivity*** super class ..i don't know if it doesn't contain ***registerForActivityResult***  function
what i am doing is trying to call ***sign in*** activity made by google library and get result back in ActivityResultLauncher using activityresultcallback

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    public static final String ANONYMOUS = "anonymous";
    public static final int DEFAULT_MSG_LENGTH_LIMIT = 1000;
    public static int num = 1;
    private ListView mMessageListView;
    private MessageAdapter mMessageAdapter;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private ImageButton mPhotoPickerButton;
    private EditText mMessageEditText;
    private Button mSendButton;
    private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference dReference;
    private String mUsername;
    private List<FriendlyMessage> friendlyMessages;

    private final ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> launcher = registerForActivityResult(new FirebaseAuthUIActivityResultContract(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<FirebaseAuthUIAuthenticationResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(FirebaseAuthUIAuthenticationResult result) {
                    onSignInResult(result);
                }
            }
    );



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user == null) {
            List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(
                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build(),
                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build());
            Intent signinIntent = AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder().setAvailableProviders(providers).build();
           startActivity(signinIntent);

        }

        // Initialize references to views
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mMessageListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messageListView);
        mPhotoPickerButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.photoPickerButton);
        mMessageEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageEditText);
        mSendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
        friendlyMessages = new ArrayList<>();
        mMessageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(this, R.layout.item_message, friendlyMessages);
        mMessageListView.setAdapter(mMessageAdapter);

        //firebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        dReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        dReference = dReference.child("Messages");
        dReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                String mess = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                mMessageAdapter.add(new FriendlyMessage(mess, "abdo", null));
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        // Initialize progress bar
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);

        // ImagePickerButton shows an image picker to upload a image for a message
        mPhotoPickerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO: Fire an intent to show an image picker
            }
        });

        // Send button sends a message and clears the EditText
        mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO: Send messages on click

                dReference.push().setValue(mMessageEditText.getText().toString());
                // Clear input box
                mMessageEditText.setText("");
                num++;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void onSignInResult(FirebaseAuthUIAuthenticationResult result)
    {
        if(result.getResultCode()==RESULT_OK)
        return;
        else
            finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: The appcompat dependency should be pulling the androix.activity one. Have you tried to `Sync project with Gradle files` so everything gets downloaded? As well as clean and rebuild your project?

Comment: Try with `-ktx` extension; but it could also be android studio issue; so try to invalidate caches and restart; also tell if you could run your app with that?

Comment: sadly i did what you recomended guys but still doesn't work

Comment: Where does this code reside? You might consider editing your question and providing the full class.

Comment: i made this code to get a result from sign in activity .
i think it doesn't matter if i include my class cause it won't be helpful in this case

Comment: The context where this is located (at least the abbreviated class to show where in the class it is and what type the class inherits from) does matter, because if the class this code resides in is not of the right type then you wouldn't be able to call class members.

Comment: ok guys i added the class that i am using 
hope you see it

Answer (score 11):

1. You need to extend **androidx.activity.ComponentActivity**
   if you want to use **androidx.activity** APIs like **registerForActivityResult**.
2. See the following example, it works with AppCompatActivity() too:

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //....

    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultLauncher;

    //....

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>(){
                    @Override
                    public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result){
                        if(result.getData() != null)
                        {
                            if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "From Activity2:    RESULT_OK\n");
                            }
                            if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "From Activity2:    CANCELLED\n");
                            }
                        }else
                        {
                            Log.d(TAG, "From Activity2:    NO DATA\n");
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    //........


    // when you wish to launch the other activity
    Intent nextActivityIntent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
    activityResultLauncher.launch(nextActivityIntent);
   ```

   }

Comment: actually issue has been solved since along time but yeah the issue was in APIS thank you for your effort man