# Android can't resolve method registerForActivityResult

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity

Even after adding dependencies, **Android Studio still can't find `registerForActivityResult()` method**. How can I fix this problem?

These dependencies has been added:

```
implementation("androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.5.0")
implementation("androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.0")
implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2")
```

And I have written this code:

```
var someActivityResultLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> = registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
    ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult> { result ->
        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            //There are no request codes
            val data = result.data

        } 
    })
```

Comment: Check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61622254/androidx-activityresultcontracts-package-not-found-class-not-found

Comment: I had similar problem and the cause what that the activity class in java was extending Activity insted of AppCompatActivity. Compiler tried to find registerForActivityResult from the kotlin extension functions. While registerForActivityResult is a member of AppCompatActivity.