# How can use ActivityResultLauncher without import androidx

Tags: java, android-studio, androidx

right I'm trying to import to my project:

```
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
```

and I tried to implement:

```
private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> intentActivityResultLauncher;
```

but I think I'm getting an error because is a legacy project
[image]

maybe any idea how can I implement without import with `androidx`

Comment: similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/61622333/12709358